# git log from a certain commit

Tags: git

i'm have following method

```
void a::someMethod(bool BoolValue)
{
if (BoolValue)
     doThis();
}
```

i'm trying to find the author of `someMethod` but all i could figure out with git log and blame is that this function was originally built into another function and i was able to find the commit it was put in there but i also opened this commit in git lab and found out that in fact these lines were moved from file to file, which means that he is not the actual author of these lines.

I tried using `git log -L someMethod:someFile.cpp`
but it only shows the commit in which the function was created, not the one in which the original lines were created, so that doesn't help me.

also I was trying to find a way to use the git log for lines from a particular commit that had those lines before they were moved to another file, but I didn't find a suitable way.

How can I try to find the author of the original lines?

Comment: Use the [git pickaxe](https://www.bram.us/2020/04/15/the-git-pickaxe-find-commits-that-added-removed-a-specific-string/) ?

Comment: Try `git log --follow`

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you so much, git pickaxe realy help me.

Comment: @knittl i will also try your suggestion a bit later, thx